# Excel Online showing cursor and text very small when typing in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Today I typed something in an excel cell and accidently used some short-cut and now when I click into a cell the cursor is very small. Also the text when I start typing is very small, the normal font size is only shown after I hit the enter key. When I start to type something then the menu options are all disabled.

I already tried all short-cuts from the excel online info and non of them worked. This issue seems to occur on different devices (notebook, pc). Creating a new file didn't work either. In the windows app everything works fine, it is just the online version that has this issue. Also I have checked the formatting and zoom factor, all of them are fine.

[image: Screen on typing]

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this so that the text is shown normal?

Comment: So far, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Yes i already tried multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox) and they all look the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having a similar issue with one of my files over the last few days. I hadn't noticed any issues with the cursor, but when I would type in a cell the letters would appear so small you couldn't read them.

I was able to fix it by opening the file in the desktop app through the "editing" button in the navbar next to the help button, selecting "open in desktop app", and then selecting "resume editing here".

Not sure exactly why that fixed it but I assume it synced whatever setting was changed with the settings on the desktop app. Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just tried the same and now in the online version it shows the cursor and text in the correct size. Changing the font and font-size is still disabled when i start typing but that is not a big problem for me. :D